# Why my window doesn't show any QPixmap picture?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpixmap

I am trying to make a basic window that shows a .gif but it doesn't. I made sure that the file is in the same directory than my main.cpp . I tried with other file extensions but it still doesn't work.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QWidget *window = new QWidget;
window->setFixedSize(640, 480);

QLabel *gif_anim = new QLabel();
QPixmap const *movie = new QPixmap("sea.gif");
gif_anim->setPixmap(*movie);

QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(gif_anim);

std::cout << movie->isNull() << std::endl;

window->setLayout(layout);
window->show();

return a.exec();
}
```

I tested with the isNull() method and it tells me that my QPixmap is null (I don't know why).

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following errors:

- QPixmap does not support the gif format, if you want to show a gif you must use QMovie.
- The path of the file is relative to the executable, not the source code, so in these I use a small command to copy files from the source code folder to the build folder.

Considering the above, the solution is:

***.pro**

```
COPY_CONFIG = sea.gif
copy_cmd.input = COPY_CONFIG
copy_cmd.output = ${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}${QMAKE_FILE_EXT}
copy_cmd.commands = $$QMAKE_COPY_DIR ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
copy_cmd.CONFIG += no_link_no_clean
copy_cmd.variable_out = PRE_TARGETDEPS
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += copy_cmd
```

**main.cpp**

```
QWidget window;
window.setFixedSize(640, 480);
QLabel *gif_anim = new QLabel();
QMovie *movie = new QMovie("sea.gif");
gif_anim->setMovie(movie);
movie->start();
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(gif_anim);
window.setLayout(layout);
window.show();
```

Comment: In the detailed description of QPixmap, it says that gif is supported : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#reading-and-writing-image-files. Despite that, I used your solution and put the sea.gif next to the executable and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Also, your *.pro lines make my compilation pause with a question in the Qt Creator "shell" : "is sea.gif a file or directory ?" I have no idea where to type the answer.

Comment: @A.Neo Are you sure that when you compiled the .gif is not deleted ?, try using the fullpath of the .gif, QPixmap allows to show the .gif but not the animation. On the other hand, the .gif is next to main.cpp?

Comment: Never mind, it works now. I should not have put the sea.gif in the same directory of the executable but one level above instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I use QMovie for gif animations instead of QPixmap:

```
QLabel *gif_anim = new QLabel();
QMovie *movie = new QMovie("sea.gif");
gif_anim->setMovie(*movie);
movie->start();
```

I usually check the supported image formats in Qt. You can do it with this code:

```
qDebug() << "Supported image formats: " << QImageReader::supportedImageFormats();
```